# jQuery Ajax Stop is not invoked (No error; 200 OK)

Tags: asp.net, json, encoding, compression, httpmodule

I have a working ASP.Net 2.0 code in my development server that uses jQuery Ajax. The result of the ajax call is used to load dropdown values.

But when this code is deployed to a new DMZ server, the result is not getting populated in dropdown – though I am getting `200 OK` as response. One obvious thing is that the `Type` is different in the response. It is expected as `application/json` but coming as `text/plain`.

I have success call back and error callback codes. Along with this I have handlers for ajax start and stop.  But none of these events are getting fired. What is the reason `error`/`stop` handlers are not getting fired? How can we make it work?

Note: The behavior is same in both IE and Chrome.

**Update**

Also observed that there is an error logged in console, as shown below. Is it related to the "**Type**"? How can we address this?

[image]

Note: Also note that the `Content-Length` is 0 in the response headers shown below.

**Success Callback**

[image]

**jQuery**

```
      function loadASN()
      {
            var receiveScanParameter = getContainerParameters();

           // console.log(receiveScanParameter);

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "rcvScanTXAdd.aspx/GetASNForPlant",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ receiveScanParameter: receiveScanParameter }),
                    success: successPopulateASN,
                    error: errorFunction
                    });
      }
```

**Global jQuery Code**

```
    //Global Ajax Error handling Function
    function errorFunction(xhr, status, error) 
    {
              if(xhr == 'undefined' || xhr == undefined)
              {
                alert('xhr undefined');
              }

              alert(status);
              alert(error);
    }


 $(document).ready(function () 
 {
    //Ajax Start
    $('body').ajaxStart(function() 
    {
        //Change cursor to waiting 
        $(this).css({'cursor':'wait'})
    });

    //Ajax End
    $('body').ajaxStop(function() {

        //Reset the cursor
        $(this).css({'cursor':'default'})

    }); 



 });
```

**Screenshots**

[image]

Comment: What is your jQuery code?

Comment: Something tells me that there's an exception thrown either in success callback or inside jQuery when it tries to parse the returned result. Probably jQuery decided that the result is success, but then an exception occurred, and since it cannot have both success and error callbacks called (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)), no other callbacks get called. Are there any errors in console?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin There is an error in the console. I have updated the question with the screenshot. [But this error is not present in my development server]

Comment: Well, now you should look inside those scripts where error occurs. Why the property is null? And why does server return `text/plain` type (this is the main question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

**Step 1**: Observed that there is an error logged in browser’s console (saying result is null). [This screenshot is updated in the question]

**Step 2**: Observed that the `content length` of the `response` is zero. Also observed that there is a `gzip` compression happened on the response (by reading the response headers).

**Step 3**: Analyzed the server's web.config. It was uisng a C# `httpModule` for `compression`. In that httpModule added bypassing logic for `json`. [I don’t want json to be compressed with this custom module. Later I will consider adding compression to JSON when I use `IIS` for compression instead of custom module]. Following is the `C#` code segment for by-passing JSON compression

```
request.ContentType.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).StartsWith("application/json")
```

---

Answer (score -1):

WHen in doubt, read the API docs:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStop() method should only be attached to document.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Same note can be found in `$.ajaxStart` docs

Comment: But can you please explain why it is working in my dev server?